# How to fix cutted/trimmed side on canvas/bitmap?

Tags: java, android, image, canvas, bitmap

Im trying to merge to bitmap using this code

```
Bitmap bitmapMerged = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            w, h,
            bitmapOriginal.getConfig()); 
            Canvas canvasMerged = new Canvas(bitmapMerged);
            canvasMerged.drawBitmap(bitmapOriginal, 0, 0, null);
            canvasMerged.drawBitmap(bitmapSecond, bitmapOriginal.getWidth(), 0, null);
```

It merge successfully, my next goal is to rotate the merged bitmap so I used this code

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix(); 
             matrix.postRotate(10); 
             canvasMerged.setMatrix(matrix);
```

But the image is cutted/trim the side it seems it didnt fit in how to fix this?

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Use `matrix.postRotate();` with center. So,

```
matrix.postRotate( 10, centerX, centerY );
```

Comment: What dO you mean by CenterX  and CenterY can you explain a little, thanks

Comment: @Joselito Macablo bitmap.getWidth()/2, bitmap.getHeight()/2